# OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) conflicts with AVFoundation: Call to 'simd_char' is ambiguous

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, avfoundation, glm-math

I am building an iOS game that includes the GLM library for performing some calculations needed in GLSL (notably - a projection matrix). I also use `AVFoundation` APIs to play videos in some screens of the app. Including GLM in the header search paths causes many of the following error if I attempt to import `AVFoundation`.

```
/Applications/Xcode_10.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/simd/conversion.h:1069:73: Call to 'simd_char' is ambiguous
```

Steps to repro this are:

1. create iOS app project in XCode
2. include glm in header search paths
3. import `AVFoundation` anywhere in the project

I have created a sample project that reproduces this issue [here](https://github.com/gh123man/GLM-conflicts-with-AVFoundation).

How can I make GLM compile with AVFoundation included?

For reference some parts of my game are in c, (for core engine) and other parts are in Swift/objc (for Cocoa/UIKit). 
I am using GLM 0.9.9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change "User Header Search Paths" instead of "Header Search path" in "Build Settings", since `AVFoundation` refers to `<..simd>`, `<...>` means "Header Search Path" in "Build Settings".

1. add `$SOURCE_ROOT/glm` to "User Header Search Paths" and remove it from  "Header Search Path" if exist
2. copy the `glm` folder to root of source